# How to disable emitEvent to all form controls

Tags: forms, angular

Is there a way to set emitEvent to false to all forms controls ?

For the moment, when we patchValue or setValue, it is possible to pass options to not throw the valueChanges of a form:

```
form.get['myControlName'].setValue('newValue', {emitEvent:false})
form.get['myControlName'].patchValue('newValue', {emitEvent:false})
```

But if we have a lot of patchValue or setValue, it is a bit repetitive... I there a way to disable the emitEvent before, change all values and active it again after ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a simple solution like this : 
iterate on all controls of you form and reset their value and set the `emitEvent` to `false`:

```
//the "manual" solution :
form.controls['name'].setValue('nameNewValue', {emitEvent:false});
form.controls['address'].setValue('addressNewValue', {emitEvent:false});

// the "dynamic" solution
for(let control in form.controls){            
    form.controls[control].setValue(form.controls[control].value, {emitEvent:false});
}
```

hope it helps :)